# Is it efficient to store sha256 hash of username in _id field in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have a special need to hash the username, and also I need to keep the usernames unique for my purpose. So, my question is can I override default '_id' field of mongoDB with sha256 hash of username? I read that _id needs to be unique and already indexed, so why would I want to create another entry instead of storing in _id.

Does this cause any technical problems which I'm unaware of? Is it efficient when searching _id as it is indexed?

This application is a Flask application using Flask-pymongo as mongo driver and helper.

By default:

_id : ObjectId(...)

I need:

_id : sha256(username)

Please explain if there are any issues with this approach.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Comment: I see, but unfortunately there is not much I could explain about this particular problem, not even code

Comment: Why do you not simply create an index on the username?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Why should I not take advantage of default _id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is no problem with using sha256 for the value of `_id`.  The default `ObjectId` type in MongoDB is convenient for creating a unique value "on the spot" but not *required*.  The bit pattern in `_id` has to be unique, that's all.

From a data design perspective, if you use a function on user data (e.g. sha256) to create material that is linked to the physical DB mechanics (like `_id`) you must make sure that the user data does not change over the lifetime  of the data.  In this case, `username` may be OK but email address for example might be poor because a user could change their email address.

Comment: We had a special requirement, so we won't allow users to change their usernames and ensure unique usernames. Also, we don't collect e-mails. Sorry for being vague about our scenario/requirements, and thnx for your time